# Android: Expand ListView to fill space between two items

Tags: android, listview

I have a ListView that is sandwiched between two buttons. The entire screen is in a `ScrollView`

```
    <Button
        android:text="Take a Picture"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/btnPicture"
        android:layout_marginRight="3dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="3dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:textSize="25dp"/>
    <ListView
        android:minWidth="25px"
        android:minHeight="25px"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/lstPhotos"
        android:visibility="gone" />
    <Button
        android:text="Location Type"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/btnLocationType"
        android:layout_marginRight="3dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="3dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:textSize="25dp" />
```

As I add items to the listview in code, how can I get the listview to take up enough space to be visible. It does expand to show 1 item but after I add the second item it doesn't expand any more.

You can see here after I added a second picture row to the listview, it's not visible.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you should never put a listview inside a scrollview! see here for example: [How can I put a ListView into a ScrollView without it collapsing?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3495890/how-can-i-put-a-listview-into-a-scrollview-without-it-collapsing)